# grep with heredoc in function

Tags: bash, here-document, bash-functions

I want to make function that parses from text pasted in a terminal.

```
$ cat <<eof | grep --color sometext
> foo
> sometext
> sometext1
> a sometext
> asdf
> 
> eof
sometext
sometext1
a sometext
```

While the above works I can make neither an alias nor a function of it.

```
alias gsi='cat <<eof | grep --color "$1"'
gsi { cat <<eof | grep --color "$1" ; }
```

I thought redirections weren't executed during function definition.

Answer (score 5):

```
alias 'gsi=<<eof grep --color'
```

Would work as alias is just like preprocessor text replacement, where the replacement is interpreted as shell code again.

Yours was not working as you had that `"$1"`. With `gsi file.txt` replaced with `cat <<eof | grep --color "$1" file.txt`, then the shell carries on interpreting that command line and `$1` at that point is the shell's first positional parameter which is probably empty unless you did a `set something` beforehand. So you'd want to remove that `"$1"` here. You can remove the UUOC as well.

```
gsi() { cat <<eof | grep --color "$1" ; }
```

is wrong from a syntax point of view as the `eof` line is missing after that `cat <<eof`.

Comment: Thanks, for emending the alias. I still don't understand why `here-document` is executed during function definition.

Comment: @1.61803 it's not that the heredoc is executed, it's that the function body has to be syntactically complete so that bash can understand how much of what you have given is the function, unlike aliases which are essentially simple text replacements.

Answer (score 4):

Your function would not be using a here-document:

```
gsi () {
   grep --color "$@"
}
```

This would enable you to pass a pattern as well as any other options to `grep` on the common line and `grep` would read from standard input.

The end of the input would be signalled by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

The above would possibly intermingle the pasted contents and the result from `grep`.  To accumulate the pasted content first and *then* run `grep`, you could use something like

```
gsi () {
    trap 'rm -f "$buffer"' RETURN
    local buffer="$(mktemp)"
    cat >"$buffer" && grep --color "$@" "$buffer"
}
```

Here, the pasted output is put into a temporary file before the `grep` is run.  The temporary file is removed when the function exits.  This is approximately what `bash` would do behind the scenes when you paste into a here-document.

Comment: This works, but is a bit awkward in that if the input is pasted to the terminal, it will get intermixed with output from `grep`. The here-doc works as a work-around for that, though I suppose one could wrap the `grep` within `stty -echo` and `stty echo` to hide the pasted text...

Comment: @ilkkachu True, the here-document in the question would act like a temporary buffer. I'll try your suggestion and make an update when I'm in front of a computer later.

Comment: @Kusalananda, ideally, I would have both pasted and `grep`ed text on screen.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you're pasting to terminal. Abandon here-doc altogether, and use a proper clipboard utility, such as `xclip` (or `pbpaste` on Mac OS X). With `xclip` that'd be done as

```
xclip -o -sel clip | grep --color 'sometext'
```

See also ['xclip' vs. 'xsel'](https://askubuntu.com/q/705620/295286) on the difference between the two utilities.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case I rather not use additional software, which by the way isn't that widespread.

Comment: @1.61803 Understandable. Hopefully, this helps to others.  `xclip` is actually a fairly common software, at least across Linux repositories.

Comment: https://repology.org/metapackage/xclip/versions